# CSS box hover popups appear behind other boxes

Tags: css, popup, z-index

I'm trying to get popups appearing as you hover over one of several boxes, and it's working fine except the other boxes appear over the top of my popup. I've tried applying z-index values to .original-box and .popup-box but no luck. I can't understand why z-index has no effect here?

Here's what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/CK4tA/

```
<div class="original-box">
    Hover over me
    <div class="popup-box popup-box-centre">
        Some popup content
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

EDIT: Awesome - thanks people! Just for my curiosity, why does adding z-index:0 to .original-box break it? That's what I had originally and didn't work. Thanks again :-)

Comment: .popup-box is the only item that needs the z-index and it's best practice to give it only on hover. it is unnecessary to apply it before hand. original-box doesn't need any z-index specified.

Answer (score 2):

add `z-index` to `.popup-box`.

```
    .popup-box {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:230px;
    height:230px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#EC006C;
    color:#FFF;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
    -o-transition:all 0.4s;
    transition:all 0.4s;
    opacity:0;
    filter:Alpha(opacity=0);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CK4tA/1/)

Add a z-index to the box to show it on the top layer.

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain?  The linked fiddle clearly works, at least in current Chrome, IE and FF.

Answer (score 0):

```
.popup-box{
   z-index:1;
}
```

If you add this to the class in your css, it will work

Answer (score 0):

you should put the `z-index` property **only on the hover** event. See below;

```
.original-box:hover .popup-box {
  top:25px;
  opacity:1;
  filter:Alpha(opacity=100);
  z-index: 20;
}
```

See your [revised JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CK4tA/2/). Hope this helps you my friend.

*Note that the `z-index` is 20, you dont want conflicts with other plugins/code using `z-index` on other items.*

Comment: When you add z-index:0 to the parent container it's child elements (ie. popup-box) inherit the z-index property too. Some browsers will cope with this, but most will break. Note that every element on the page has a z-index of 0 by default.

Comment: However elements are stacked and so therefore, siblings will always appear slightly higher, if positioned absolute for example. Hope the advice helped. Note* i always use increments of 10 or 20 so that if i later need to adjust 1 items z-index i dont need to edit several at the same time